# What is the issue with this C code which has a error?

Tags: c, pointers

It is a code written to copy one pointer to another.
ERROR is Segmentation error (core Dumped)

```
#include<stdio.h>
char strcp(char *,char *);
int main()
{
char *p="string",*q;
printf("%s",p);
strcp(p,q);
printf("%s",q);
return 0;
}
char strcp(char *p,char *q)
{
int i;
for(i=0;*(p+i)!='\0';i++)
*(p+i)=*(q+i);
}
```

Comment: `q` points to garbage.

Comment: Your strcp command copies characters from q to p.  Is this what you want?

Comment: yes but it gives an error

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to copy from p to q instead?

Comment: even if I write *(q+i)=*(p+i) it gives same error

Comment: Usually people write `p[i]` instead of `*(p+i)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *p="string"...
strcp(p,q);
```

What `p` points to is a literal and literals are read-only. Trying to copy anything to it is forbidden (and causes a segmentation fault).

...and `q` is not initialized, another possible cause of the seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this algorithm is an implicit assumption it makes about pointers: `char *q` is *not* a string, it is a pointer to character. It can be treated as a `string` if you allocate space and place a null-terminated sequence of characters into it, but your code does not do it.

You can allocate space to `q` with `malloc`, like this:

```
char *p="string";
char *q=malloc(strlen(p)+1);
```

In addition, your version of `strcpy` reads null terminator from a wrong pointer, and does not null-terminate the copied string:

```
char strcp(char *p, char *q)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;*(q+i)!='\0';i++) // <<== Fix this
        *(p+i)=*(q+i);
    *(p+i) = '\0'; // <<== Add this line
}
```

Comment: ..and then `strcpy(q,p);`

Comment: If I do the above change it is printing *p value 2 times

Comment: @Satya Isn't that your goal? When you print `p`, then you make a copy into `q`, and print `q`, you see the content of `p` printed two times. If you want to see some separation between the printouts, add `"%s\n"` to go to next line.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Not really, he's using it as he intended (the inverse of the standard).

Answer (score -1):

As the other answers have indicated the problem **starts*** with `char *p="string",*q;`.
The [Literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)) `"string"` compiles to the equivalent:

`const char foo[7] = {'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'};` [why *\0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)

As you might see further in you code you're trying to copy data to a `const` a\rray. Which is illegal.

But you're playing C, you have [implicitly casted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Implicit_type_conversion) the `const char foo[]` to a `char *p`, right there during [initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)).

C is not [type safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) because it's tightly coupled to the actual instruction on the hardware. Where types don't exist anymore, just widths. But that is for another topic.

**It's not the only flaw. I tossed in a few explanatory wiki links. Because the question shows you're a novice programmer. Keep up the work.*